# how to drain all logs in a space to syslog in cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, syslog

I am trying to drain all logs from cloud foundry apps to a thirdparty software, I have tried with https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-drain-cli but no luck.

I am able to drain individual app logs without any issue. But simply there are two many logs.

Unlike drain individual application log, drain a space log seems require additional download from internet.

Comment: Please tell in description what you are trying to do. It isn't helpful when the question is not detailed at all and nobody can understand. Also, supply some code, if there is any, to make your question more detailed. Last thing, pleasre have good grammar. Thanks!!

Comment: `cf-drain-cli` is the answer, so you should probably rephrase or make a new question around how that tool is failing, what errors you see, exactly what is the problem you are having.